# How to delete a set of characters from a file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to delete a set of characters from a file.
The sample file is as follows . I want to delete  characters preceding the '-' (including '-')in the 8th column (separator=',').
sample file:

```
aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,ff-gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,ff-gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,ff-gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,ff-gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,ff-gjgj,dd,dd,dd
```

The output file should look like as:

```
aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd

aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj second one wouldn't work as it would have to match 8 `-`s

Comment: Can the 8th field ever have multiple `-`s, e.g. `ff-gj-gj`? If so what would the expected output be - `gj-gj` or `gj` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^[^-]*-/, "", $8)} 1' file
aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd
aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd
aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd
aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd
aa,bb,cc,dd,ff,rr,dd,gjgj,dd,dd,dd
```